# Count time for SQL update

Tags: java

I want to create a Java code which makes benchmark about importing xml file into SQL table. I tried this:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class Application extends SqlUtils {

    private static String folderPath = "D:\\EntityImportEversana";

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        System.out.println("Running file verifier");
        System.out.println("monitoring folder " + folderPath);
        SqlUtils sql = new SqlUtils();

        WatchService watchService = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();
        Path path = Paths.get(folderPath);
        path.register(watchService, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_DELETE, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY);
        WatchKey key;
        while ((key = watchService.take()) != null) {
            for (WatchEvent<?> event : key.pollEvents()) {
                System.out.println("Event kind:" + event.kind() + ". File affected: " + event.context() + ".");
                if(event.kind().equals(StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_DELETE)){
                    // Here we make a constant pull and we get the status using sql from db.
                    // make here start of benchmark 
                    HashMap<String, List> map = sql.checkFileImport();

                    // end here of benchmark

                }

            }
            key.reset();
        }

        watchService.close();
    }
}
```

Do you know how I can make a benchmark into the above code and trace when the file is updated into db?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can measure the time like this:

```
Instant start = Instant.now();

... // do your import here

Instant end = Instant.now();
System.out.println(Duration.between(start,end));
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you show me how I can make a constant pool to Java method which makes SQL queries?

Comment: How about you create a separate question for that?